# Why does my WordPress plugin send websites into an unstoppable refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, plugins

I am a novice PHP programmer and I try to make Wordpress Plugins in my free time.

In the course of developing and enhancing my plugin, I tried to add a feature in which
the css classes and ids of the dialog widgets, which are created and shown by the plugin, are all randomized.

In trying to do this, I set those random classes and ids in the PHP session in a PHP file included into the main plugin
index.php file and pass those classes and ids to the JavaScript and CSS files.

Please note that I called session_write_close() after I finished setting the required variables in session in the included PHP file.

```
<?php

@session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"]))
{ 
    $eazy_ad_words_path = plugins_url('file/words.txt', dirname(__FILE__));
    
    $eazy_ad_fileWords = @file_get_contents($eazy_ad_words_path, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
    
    if($eazy_ad_fileWords === false) //if file not read for some reason
    {
        $eazy_ad_wordsArray = array("word1","word2","word3","word4","word5","word6","word7","word8");
        
        $_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"] = $eazy_ad_wordsArray;
    }
    else{
        
        $eazy_ad_wordsArray = explode("\n", $eazy_ad_fileWords);
        
        $eazy_ad_randWordsKeys = array_rand($eazy_ad_wordsArray, 8);
        
        $eazy_ad_randWordElems = array();
        
        foreach($eazy_ad_randWordsKeys as $key)
        {
            $eazy_ad_randWordElems[] = $eazy_ad_wordsArray[$key];
        }
        
        $_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"] = $eazy_ad_randWordElems;
    
    }

}



$prefix_array = array("a","b","e", "u");

shuffle($prefix_array);

$eazy_ad_unblocker_str1 = implode("", $prefix_array)."_";

$eazy_ad_unblocker_holder_id = '';

if(isset($_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"]))
{
    $eazy_ad_unblocker_holder_id = $_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"][0].'-'.md5(microtime());
}
else
{
    $eazy_ad_unblocker_holder_id = $eazy_ad_unblocker_str1.md5(microtime());
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_HOLDER_ID']))
{
    //
    $_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_HOLDER_ID'] =  $eazy_ad_unblocker_holder_id;
}

shuffle($prefix_array);

$eazy_ad_unblocker_holder_class_name = '';

$eazy_ad_unblocker_str2 = implode("", $prefix_array)."_";

if(isset($_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"]))
{
    $eazy_ad_unblocker_holder_class_name = $_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"][1].'-'.md5(microtime());
}
else
{
    $eazy_ad_unblocker_holder_class_name = $eazy_ad_unblocker_str2.md5(microtime());
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_HOLDER_CLASS_NAME']))
{
    
    $_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_HOLDER_CLASS_NAME'] =  $eazy_ad_unblocker_holder_class_name;
}

shuffle($prefix_array);

$eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_overlay_id = '';

$eazy_ad_unblocker_str3 = implode("", $prefix_array)."_";

if(isset($_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"]))
{

    $eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_overlay_id = $_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"][2].'-'.md5(microtime());

}
else{
    $eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_overlay_id = $eazy_ad_unblocker_str3.md5(microtime());
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_DIALOG_OVERLAY_ID']))
{
    //
    $_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_DIALOG_OVERLAY_ID'] =  $eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_overlay_id;
}

shuffle($prefix_array);

$eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_parent_id = '';

$eazy_ad_unblocker_str4 = implode("", $prefix_array)."_";

if(isset($_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"]))
{
    $eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_parent_id = $_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"][3].'-'.md5(microtime());
}
else
{
    $eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_parent_id = $eazy_ad_unblocker_str4.md5(microtime());
}


if(!isset($_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_DIALOG_PARENT_ID']))
{   
    $_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_DIALOG_PARENT_ID'] =  $eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_parent_id;
}

shuffle($prefix_array);

$eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_message_id = '';

$eazy_ad_unblocker_str5 = implode("", $prefix_array)."_";

if(isset($_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"]))
{
    $eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_message_id = $_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"][4].'-'.md5(microtime());
}
else{
    $eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_message_id = $eazy_ad_unblocker_str5.md5(microtime());
}



if(!isset($_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_DIALOG_MESSAGE_ID']))
{
    
    $_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_DIALOG_MESSAGE_ID'] =  $eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_message_id;
    
}

shuffle($prefix_array);

$eazy_ad_unblocker_refresh_btn_class = '';


$eazy_ad_unblocker_str6 = implode("", $prefix_array)."_";

if(isset($_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"]))
{
    $eazy_ad_unblocker_refresh_btn_class = $_SESSION["eazy_ad_rand_words"][5].'-'.md5(microtime());
}
else{
    $eazy_ad_unblocker_refresh_btn_class = $eazy_ad_unblocker_str6.md5(microtime());
}



if(!isset($_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_REFRESH_BTN_CLASS']))
{
    
    $_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_REFRESH_BTN_CLASS'] =  $eazy_ad_unblocker_refresh_btn_class;
    
}

//April 10 2021

session_write_close();

//End April 10 2021

$eazy_ad_unblocker_popup_params_array = array("eazy_ad_unblocker_holder"=> $_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_HOLDER_ID'],
    "eazy_ad_unblocker_holder_class_name" => $_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_HOLDER_CLASS_NAME'],
    "eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_overlay"=> $_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_DIALOG_OVERLAY_ID'],
    "eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_parent" => $_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_DIALOG_PARENT_ID'],
    "eazy_ad_unblocker_dialog_message" => $_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_DIALOG_MESSAGE_ID'],
    "eazy_ad_unblocker_refresh_btn_class" => $_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_REFRESH_BTN_CLASS']);
```

For the JavaScript, I simply used the wp_localize_script() function and it works.

For the CSS, I created a PHP file calling it style.css.php and I call the PHP header function at the top of the file
passing the Content-Type as text/css. I then called the session variables after calling session_start() in the top of the
style.css.php and then set styles for those classes and ids retrieved from session. I am not using cookies as I believe
they can be deleted from web developer tools by savvy users.

In this style.css.php I have called the header function and session in the following way:

```
<?php

@session_start();
header("Content-Type: text/css;charset=utf-8"); 

?>

<?php echo '#'.$_SESSION['EAZY_AD_UNBLOCKER_DIALOG_PARENT_ID'];  ?> .ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-dialog-titlebar-close{ display: none !important;}
```

There are other stylesheets created for theming in the same way as the style.css.php file.
These files contain the header and session_start functions in the same way as the style.css.php

The URL of these files with extension .css.php are called as stylesheet URLs in the popup in front end.

The thing is that some users of the plugin report that in Litespeed server with PHP 7.4 and WordPress 5.7.1,
running cloudflare CDN plugin along with my plugin, my plugin causes the web pages to go into a refresh
or redirect loop.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/new-updates-1-1-6-has-a-bug-continuously-refresh-webpages/

The plugin is working fine at https://myplugins.net/demo/

Just visit this site with an ad blocker active in your browser.
(Microsoft Edge, FireFox, Google Chrome and Opera browsers are supported)

I don't get what the issue is. Am I calling session_start and header functions in the wrong way?
Or is it some other issue since Litespeed cache or Cloudflare CDN are being used?

The following things have changed since version 1.1.5:

1. attempting to set css classes and css ids of dialog widgets in PHP session variables in an included PHP file
   named constants.php (code given above)
2. passing those classes and ids to javascript and css files
3. passing classes and ids to javascript using wp_localize_script function from
   PHP session.
4. creating css stylesheets as PHP files with Content-Type headers as text/css MIME type and calling them
   in front end. (code given above)
5. calling the css classes and ids from PHP session and setting styles for them in the CSS files of
   point number 4 above
6. encapsulating some continuous javascript code in a function named 'eazy_ad_unblocker_aspect_ratio' and
   calling the function in place of the continuous code. (in a file named custom.js)
7. called the session_write_close() in constants.php in version 1.1.7 of the plugin.

Thanks and regards,
Pratyush

Comment: According to the support question in the forum it works with version 1.1.5 and not with version 1.1.6.  What exactly has changed between the two versions?

Comment: @Aaron, have provided what has changed since version 1.1.5 of the plugin